# Weight sharing in Keras

Tags: python, keras, share

I am trying to use same weight for two layers which are named `dense3` in the code below. I know using `dense3` as name is not allowed as layers need to have unique names.

What is the best was to specify same weight different layers in Keras?

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu,name='dense_1'),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='dense_2'),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu,name='dense_3' ),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu,name='dense_3' ),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sharedLayer = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu,name='dense_3' )

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu,name='dense_1'),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='dense_2'),
    sharedLayer,
    sharedLayer,
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
```